# Jmeter xpath extractor

Tags: jmeter

Hi
 I am new to JMeter. I was trying to extract the response values from the response xml and store it back in a csv file or an excel file. I am not able to do so.
Can someone help me out on this matter.

Comment: Your question have 3 different parts to it? 1. Are you not able to get the regex extractor itself working? 2. Are you not able to write the extracted values in CSV file? 3. OR Your output XML is complex and you are having problem parsing it? Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a Beanshell script to this, as Jmeter doesn't naively have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had come across similar scenario and my suggestion would be to write a SAX parser in pure java and add it as jar in Jmeter lib folder.
A Bean Shell Post processor can be used to import this jar and pass the response xml to the parsing method. Good Luck